# Android intent album gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I want to do a intent to the gallery for take a photo. It's easy to find a lot of examples that do this, but i want that open the gallery in my own album directly. it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this:

```
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

// ... 

Intent in = new Intent();
in.setType("image/*");
in.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

String pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"; // Or get from strings.xml
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(in, pickTitle);
chooserIntent.putExtra
(
  Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, 
  new Intent[] { takePhotoIntent }
);

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Comment: thanks, this works, but i want a direct intent to the gallery but in my own folder.